# New "Custom Types" item in admin menu. Is this a plugin or a new wordpress feature?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, admin

I just noticed I have a "Custom Types" menu item on my wordpress backend (admin) menu.

Picture:

[image]

I tried disabling every plugin that has anything to do with custom post types and it was still there. So then I disabled *every* plugin in the backend and someone it is still there. New wordpress feature? Or what did I do?

Comment: Could it be a feature of your theme? What happens if you change theme?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook that was it! I didn't think of that. I think I should close this question.

Comment: Add it as your own answer and accept it to keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by the JointsWP theme. In the functions.php file on line #37 there is a commented line that I uncommented. It enables a post types ui kind of view.

This was not a plugin nor a wordpress built-in feature. It is in fact a feature of JointsWP